# Prestashop - 1.7.4.2 - double if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, prestashop, conditional-statements

I'm facing a (new) problem with Prestashop 1.7.4.2. I want to check if certain product ID is in cart before allowing a customer to proceed to the checkout. If not, I want to display an alert.

It works like this :

```
{if !Context::getContext()->cart->containsProduct(784)}
message
{/if}
```

- I want to add a second if statement to check if there is a certain number of products in cart.

If there is less than xx products in cart AND/OR if cart containsProduct(784), I want to display message.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
Context::getContext()->cart->containsProduct(784) // number of products 784 in cart
```

AND

```
Cart::getNbProducts(Context::getContext()->cart->id) // number of products in cart
```

Regards